# Async hell in express middlewere

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a problem caused by async being used and things not being in sync (yes i know it's common), this is how it looks like:

First the express router gets the call from a url, then it calls a middlewere function

```
router.post('/', checkFunction, (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('somepage.ejs', {
        output: res.locals.output;
    });
});
```

Now inside the checkFunction which used to be callback only, i now make a call to another function which uses axios and has to be async

```
function checkFunction(req, res, next) {
    if ('check') secondFunction(req, res, next);
next()
}
```

The last function looks like this, it checks the input from the user page for an empty string, a good request and a bad one, and returns the output to the user, empty good or bad.
on the bad one it executes a tail command to fetch data from the logs about the error

```
async function secondFunction(req, res, next) {
    const url = 'http://somepage.com';
    if ('some check on req') res.locals.output = 'nothing';
    else {
        try {
            const data = await axios.get(url);
            res.locals.output = 'good request';
        } catch (error) {
            exec(`tail -n 1 file.log`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                console.log('err:', error);
                console.log('stdout:', stdout);
                console.log('stderr:', stderr);
                res.locals.output = stdout;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is (as expected) the second function runs before the axios request is done, leaving the output\exec command waiting for it as well, then the check function finishes with undefined since the output hasn't been set and the same returns all the way to the user who gets an empty page...

Now i have tried lots of combo with await\async, promises and other witchery from google but none of them helped getting it to sync right, i think i need to make chained promises to get this to sync but i don't know how exactly and since the check function is being used by other routes as well it's a general function and i really don't want to duplicate the code just to handle this weird situation.

Well that's about it, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm modifying my answer with two options and error handling. You can wait till 'secondFunction' executes in two ways.

1. Wrap exec with a promise
2. Use callback

**Option 1: Wrap with promise**

```
async function checkFunction(req, res, next) {
    if('check') {
        try{
            await secondFunction(req, res, next);
            next();
        }catch(ex) {
            throw new Error('Error', ex);
        }
    }else{
        next(); //or throw error or redirect
    }
}

async function secondFunction(req, res, next) {
    const url = 'http://somepage.com';
    if ('some check on req') res.locals.output = 'nothing';
    else {

        try {
            const data = await axios.get(url);
            res.locals.output = 'good request';

        } catch (error) {
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                exec(`tail -n 1 file.log`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                    if(error) {
                        console.log('err:', error);
                        reject(error);
                    }else {
                        console.log('stdout:', stdout);
                        console.log('stderr:', stderr);
                        res.locals.output = stdout;

                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Use callback**

```
function checkFunction(req, res, next) {
    if('check') {
        secondFunction(req, res, (err) => {
            if(err) {
                //or throw error or redirect
            }else{
                next();
            }
        });

    }else{
        next(); //or throw error or redirect
    }
}

function secondFunction(req, res, callback) {
    const url = 'http://somepage.com';
    if ('some check on req') {
        res.locals.output = 'nothing';
        callback();
    } else {
        axios.get(url).then((response) => {
            res.locals.output = 'good request';
            callback();
        }).catch(err => {
            exec(`tail -n 1 file.log`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('err:', error);
                    callback(error);
                } else {
                    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
                    console.log('stderr:', stderr);
                    res.locals.output = stdout;

                    callback();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Also child_process.execSync() method is generally identical to child_process.exec() with the exception that the method will not return until the child process has fully closed

```
var logs = execSync(`tail -n 1 file.log`);
console.log(logs);
```

But please note that this will block your IO operations.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the next function when posting the question, checkFunction does have it since it's a middleware function but as for the secondFunction, i didn't see the point, if it's not a middleware function it will return to the checkFunction, am i wrong?

Comment: Ok, just doubled check it, tried what you suggested. i got an even earlier response from the callback function for the route so i'm assuming the next function is also an async function and by calling it i have actually forced it to go to the next middleware which doesn't exist so it reached the callback first then resolved the checkFunction and the secondFunction by order of execution...

Comment: I did some modifications to the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: `secondFunction()` would need to either `return` or `await` the promise you wrapped around `exec()`.  As it is, `secondFunction()` still does not communicate back when `exec()` is done.

Comment: Yes. I think its need await. I will modify the answer

Comment: There should be some error handling on the call to `exec()` too.  And, NEVER recommend `execSync()` in a server processing incoming requests.  That is never a good recommendation.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have added error handling and update the code with two options

Comment: @nuwan-niroshana thank you! it finally works as needed. You have no idea how much time i spent on this, so much that in fact i still don't understand the answer lol.

Can you please clarify the fallowing:
1. I still don't see the point of next() after calling secondFunction() as i said checkFunction is a global middleware i use so after that if statement that runs secondFunction it still has things to do and run and at the end it runs next, any reason running next before the middleware is finished? secondFunction is just an additional value that could be used if needed.

Comment: the previous comment was about the await solution as it had next in the try statement, on the callback solution, if you pass err as the third value in the call, doesn't it more sense to call next(err) to pass the error to express?

Comment: Basically, next is just the name of the function which is executing after calling the middleware function. You can call multiple functions if you want. In your case, it won't execute the res.render part if you don't call next().

Check this out https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: @nuwan-niroshana that is true but i'm executing next() after the big if statment so it goes like this:
checkfunction -> if(check) then execute secondfunction -> if checking some other thing that may come from second function or not  OR else execute other version of this in another situation -> execute next

So secondfunction is actually optional and even without it there is a next at the end of check function and i don't want to call it before the rest of the function runs the other code....

Comment: the callback solution isn't correct since it still has the axios await which forces the function to be async so one would need to break it down to callbacks as well, but i like the promise based one anyway, less callbacks is always better.

Comment: So at the end per my understanding it seems i was only missing a promise(with some error code) around exec which caused everything to be out of sync... lesson learned

Thanks again nuwan-niroshana and also @jfriend00